# Make "CREATE EXTENSION" not fail if extension is unavailable

Tags: sql, postgresql, compatibility

In a migration script, I have the following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION json;
```

The problem is, in some versions of PostgreSQL, it seems that JSON is built in, and in others, it's available as an extension.

How can I make `CREATE EXTENSION ...` not fail if the extension I try to create isn't available?

Answer (score 2):

A few functions that might be handy:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-available-extensions.html

In addition to checking before issuing the statement, you could wrap the code in a `do` statement and catch errors:

```
do $$
begin
  ; -- do something
exception
when ...
  ; -- do something different
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html